# SharePoint SSRS Blank Screen

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, ssrs-2008-r2

My Script in Database is doing for 12 minutes but SSRS is working only 10 minutes in SharePoint. When 10 minutes ends loading is disappearing and I can see only white screen. What I have do? Is there default value - where?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here on BIDS [image]

and Here on the Report Manager[image: Here2]